# Cant access property file from a jar which is added as dependency in my maven project

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a Project called mainProject and it has a maven dependency of a project called jarProject. The jarProject has a property file which comes as part of the jar. On running the mainProject in my IDE I dont get any issues and it runs fine.
When I deploy this mainProject as a Bundle on JBoss server it gives error as it is not able to find this jarProject property file. 
Please suggest what can be done to make the jarProject property file available to the mainProject on deployment.

Comment: Please provide some code to supplement your question.

Comment: Cant give the code here due to security reasons. But my question is very generic. I am building my project as a bundle package. This bundle has a reference to a jar, ie; the jar is added as a dependency in my project pom.  This jar contains a property file. When I build my project and deploy it on JBoss server it gives an error for property file from that jar not found. So my query here is, do I need to do some special setting to get that jars property file in my deployed project.